# Scope hoisting/tree shaking in parcel V2

Tags: bundler, parceljs

Do I need to specify the experimental scope hoisting/tree shaking flag (in **parcel 2.0**) to use tree shaking?

```
parcel build entry.js --experimental-scope-hoisting
```

Or tree shaking is not longer a experimental feature in parcel 2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [this](https://medium.com/@devongovett/parcel-2-beta-1-improved-stability-tree-shaking-source-map-performance-and-more-78179779e8b7#4667) article regarding Parcel v2 beta 1 (which was released on June 18th, 2020), tree shaking is enabled by default